# Use 'any' to tell you true/false, if a list contains some value(s) divisible by 42

Tags: haskell

Having fun working through a Haskell tutorial...

One problem posed is as you see in the subject line... this is one I'd really like to figure out, but I'm at a loss... I've used `any` like so:

```
ghci >any (==55) [15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,95]
True
ghci >any (==55) [15,25,35,45,54,65,75,85,95]
False
ghci >all even [2,4,6,8]
True
ghci >all even [1,3,5,7,9]
False
```

and it seems like checking if a list element is divisible by 42 or not, should be fairly easy...

I mean, you would check if any of the numbers in the list are `` n `mod` 42 == 0 ``, right?

But how do you state that in the expression?  Or do you need to write a 'helper' function?

Comment: Without a helper definition, the most straightforward way would be with an anonymous function (a "lambda").

Comment: Holy cow, thank you everyone... i had actually thought of the lambda way later, but couldn't figure out putting together the function for some reason... but once i see it, I'm like, "that makes total sense".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Composing `(0==)` and `` (`mod 42`) ``:

```
f :: [Integer] -> Bool
f = any ((0==).(`mod` 42))
```

futher reducing parenthesis noise:

```
f :: [Integer] -> Bool
f = any $ (0==).(`mod` 42)
```

Helper function:

```
f :: [Integer] -> Bool
f = any div42
  where
    div42 n = n `mod` 42 == 0
```

Stylistically, for this function, either way seems fine. However, say you wanted to check if any values are divisible by 42 **OR** 52, then utilizing composition may become more obfuscated/complex/futile. Whereas using a helper function keeps things readable: `` div42Or52 n = n `mod` 42 == 0 || n `mod` 52 == 0 ``. Note, I've used a `where` clause above, but a `let in` expression or a lambda are possible alternative ways to structure helper functions.

Ultimately, its up to the developer to balance concise code with understandable code.

Comment: For point-free code, it often helps readability to factor things into many small, generic, reusable definitions. For example, in this case I might write ``divisibleBy d = (== 0) . (`mod` d)`` (“to be divisible by *d* means to be equal to zero modulo *d*”) and then use `any (divisibleBy 42)`. Nothing wrong with using a lambda or auxiliary definition in a `where` clause, though.

Comment: @JonPurdy, I completely agree. The only challenge is figuring out the order of the arguments. `isDivisibleBy x y` sends a different message than ``x `isDivisibleBy` y``.

Comment: @dfeuer: Yeah, same problem with other names really; `divides` with the same definition but used as ``any (42 `divides`)`` makes just as much sense, but `divides 42` is the wrong way around. This is why I prefer functions not be named such that they’re intended to be used infix, because it’s in conflict with using them in prefix; if you do want infix, an operator is preferable. (Besides, I have a personal objection to grave accents being used as quotation characters in a programming language, haha)

Answer (score 8):

You can define function inplace:

```
any (\n -> n `mod` 42 == 0) [1, 2, 42]
```